# SQL Rollup - I think

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of student results in a MS SQL database. Each student result is made up of a level and grade. I have attached a screen shot. The intReportID field is crucial to tying them together. The key is TblReportsStoreGradesID

In my output I want the level and grade to appear in the same row. Can someone give me a pointer please because I am lost.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The SQL statement is SELECT        TblReportsStoreGrades.TblReportsStoreGradesID, TblReportsStoreGrades.intReportID, TblReportsStoreGrades.txtGrade
FROM            TblReportsStoreGrades INNER JOIN
                         TblReportsStore ON TblReportsStoreGrades.intReportID = TblReportsStore.TblReportsStoreID
WHERE        (TblReportsStore.intReportCycle = 68)

Comment: Please edit your question to add that code (formatted), then delete your comment.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as text in your question, not an [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Look at `lag() & lead()`

Answer (score 2):

Your `ROLLUP` intuition isn't right, but is heading is the right direction.

You want to collapse multiple rows to single rows; that's aggregation, so `GROUP BY`.  Then you need some logic to determine which row's value goes to which column in the output, you haven't explained that, so I'll just use `MIN()` and `MAX()`

```
SELECT
  g.intReportID,
  MIN(g.txtGrade)   txtGrade_min,
  MAX(g.txtGrade)   txtGrade_max
FROM
  TblReportsStore        AS s
INNER JOIN
  TblReportsStoreGrades  AS g
    ON g.intReportID = s.TblReportsStoreID
WHERE
  s.intReportCycle = 68
GROUP BY
  g.intReportID
```

If you have other useful columns, you might be able to use something like this instead (to pick which rows go in to which columns)...

```
MAX(CASE WHEN g.value_type = 'level' THEN g.txtGrade END)  AS level,
MAX(CASE WHEN g.value_type = 'grade' THEN g.txtGrade END)  AS grade
```

Comment: Ok, not sure I get the MAX concept.

Comment: Ok, got it. I used the intGradeID field to pick rows.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT        MAX(CASE WHEN g.intGradeID = 32 THEN g.txtGrade END) AS level, MAX(CASE WHEN g.intGradeID = 33 THEN g.txtGrade END) AS grade, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForename, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSurname,
TblTeachingManagerSubjects.txtSubjectName
FROM            TblReportsStore AS s INNER JOIN
TblReportsStoreGrades AS g ON g.intReportID = s.TblReportsStoreID INNER JOIN
TblPupilManagementPupils ON s.txtSchoolID = TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID INNER JOIN
TblTeachingManagerSets ON s.txtSubID = TblTeachingManagerSets.txtSetCode INNER JOIN
TblTeachingManagerSubjects ON TblTeachingManagerSets.intSubject = TblTeachingManagerSubjects.TblTeachingManagerSubjectsID
WHERE        (s.intReportCycle = 68)
GROUP BY g.intReportID, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForename, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSurname, TblTeachingManagerSubjects.txtSubjectName

Comment: Please format your answer with carriage returns and indents between the SQL clauses and include an explanation.

Comment: But none of your posted tables has a `intGradeID` column and obviously your actual schema is far more complicated than implied by your original post. You should get some expert help when designing databases.